# How to sort by number of counts in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to bring the two biggest numbers and how many it.

1. picture is a table, table name SatisBasligi.
2. picture is a output.

How can I write a code for picture?

One needs to write code according to the second.

[image]

[image]

> select sbb.musteriId, count(1) from SatisBaslik  sbb group by
>   sbb.musteriId having count(1) = (select x.adet from  (select  count(1)
>   adet from SatisBaslik sb group by sb.musteriId having
>   count(1)
>
> "(select x.adet from  (select  count(1) adet from SatisBaslik sb group
>   by sb.musteriId having count(1)

Comment: It would be much helpful if you would add your tables (formatted as text) as part of your question. By the way: What have you tried up til now?

Comment: Please remove the pictures and copy and paste their text here instead. Many don't have access to images and can not see what you are asking. Then: don't only show the desired result, but tell us why you select those rows and not others. What is the criteria? Do you want aggregations for musteriId 7, 8, and 9? Do you want all musteriId with a count > 1? Something else still?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select musteriId, count(musteriId) from SatisBasligi where musteriId in (7, 8, 9);
```

Comment: select sbb.musteriId, count(1) from
SatisBaslik  sbb
group by sbb.musteriId
having count(1) = (select x.adet from  (select  count(1) adet from SatisBaslik sb group by sb.musteriId having count(1)<max(sb.musteriId)) x)

 I  try this code but "(select x.adet from  (select  count(1) adet from SatisBaslik sb group by sb.musteriId having count(1)<max(sb.musteriId)) x)"  I just  chance here but I didn't can you guy help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group By` and `Having` clause

```
select musteriId, count(musteriId) 
from SatisBasligi 
Group by musteriId
Having count(musteriId) > 1
```

Comment: select sbb.musteriId, count(1) from
SatisBaslik  sbb
group by sbb.musteriId
having count(1) = (select x.adet from  (select  count(1) adet from SatisBaslik sb group by sb.musteriId having count(1)<max(sb.musteriId)) x)

 I  try this code but "(select x.adet from  (select  count(1) adet from SatisBaslik sb group by sb.musteriId having count(1)<max(sb.musteriId)) x)"  I just  chance here but I didn't can you guy help me ?

Comment: @RoseTyler - Sorry I didn't understand.. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve or add sample data and expected result in question

Answer (score 0):

For mysql:

```
  select musteriId, count(*)
  from SatisBasligi
  group by musteriId
  having count(musteriId) > 1
```

Comment: select sbb.musteriId, count(1) from
SatisBaslik  sbb
group by sbb.musteriId
having count(1) = (select x.adet from  (select  count(1) adet from SatisBaslik sb group by sb.musteriId having count(1)<max(sb.musteriId)) x)

 I  try this code but ".....(select x.adet from  (select  count(1) adet from SatisBaslik sb group by sb.musteriId having count(1)<max(sb.musteriId)) x)"  I just  chance here but I didn't can you guy help me ?

Comment: @Rose Tyler: All answers get the desired result, but you post this code comment. What is this supposed to mean? Do the answers work for you or not? If not: why not? What do they do differently what you want?

Comment: @Rose Tyler: This is not my code. And I am pretty sure it is working and shows exactly the result in the image for the table data shown. "not working" doesn't tell us anything. Please don't ever say this without an explanation. Do you get an error message? No rows? Undesired rows? In which way undesired? Meanwhile you have altered your question, telling us you want the musteriIds with the two highest counts. You should have explained that from the start rather than have us guess. We can only answer what you ask.

Comment: I tried and could not get a result because it gives an error

Comment: @Rose Tyler: **An** error? **Which** error??? Is this so hard? Do you think we can read minds or see your screen? I think it's time you use your brain. The query shown is proper standard SQL by the way and should run in about every DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the greatest two counts, use `ORDER BY` with `TOP` and include `WITH TIES` in order to get musteriIds with the same count.

```
select top(2) with ties
  musteriId,
  count(*)
from SatisBasligi
group by musteriId
order by count(*) desc;
```